# Rails Paperclip upload button not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, paperclip, image-uploading

I try to integrate Paperclip to my Web App. The problem is, that the upload button is not working. I can choose a file, enter a title etc. but when i hit on upload nothing happens.

when i remove in the _form.html.erb file the

```
<%= form_for @video, url: videos_path, html: { multipart: true } do |form| %>


<%= form.file_field :image %>



 <% end %>
```

the upload button is working again, but again, without the paperclip attachment.

Any ideas how to fix this?

**_form.html.erb File**

```
    <div class="container">

<%= form_for(@video) do |f| %>
  <% if @video.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@video.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this video from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @video.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :jwPlayer %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :jwPlayer %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :title %>
  </div>
  <%= form_for @video, url: videos_path, html: { multipart: true } do |form| %>
  <%= form.file_field :image %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

**Video_controller**

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_video, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /videos
  # GET /videos.json
  def index
    @videos = Video.all
  end

  # GET /videos/1
  # GET /videos/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /videos/new
  def new
    @video = Video.new
  end

  # GET /videos/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /videos
  # POST /videos.json
  def create
    @video = Video.new(video_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @video.save
        format.html { redirect_to @video, notice: 'Video was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @video }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @video.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /videos/1
  # PATCH/PUT /videos/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @video.update(video_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @video, notice: 'Video was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @video }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @video.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /videos/1
  # DELETE /videos/1.json
  def destroy
    @video.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to videos_url, notice: 'Video was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_video
      @video = Video.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def video_params
      params.require(:video).permit(:jwPlayer, :description, :title, :image)
    end
end
```

**Video.rb**

```
 class Video < ActiveRecord::Base



  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

end
```

Comment: Can you post error/logs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your code.

Add this to your code:

```
 <%= f.file_field :image %>
```

instead of this:

```
<%= form_for @video, url: videos_path, html: { multipart: true } do |form| %>
  <%= form.file_field :image %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: and add to form this: html: { multipart: true }

Comment: Thanks. Your answer was the solution! It works now perfectly fine!